# Realtek 8852BE driver missing even though it should be available

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I have an HP laptop with an Realtek 8852BE wifi card, and I am unable to use the driver even though the driver for it is supposed to be [included in the kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers) after 5.16+ as per `lwfinger` [README.md](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89#readme).

**How can I use the driver available in the kernel assuming it is actually available?**

Currently I am using this driver, but it is deprecated: https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be

I had also tried this driver, but it was unstable: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

Running `sudo lshw -C network` returns:

```
*-network                 
    description: Wireless interface
    product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    logical name: wlo1
    version: 00
    serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8852be driverversion=v1.15.6.0.2-0-gac110bf5.2021102 firmware=N/A ip=192.xxx.xxx.xxx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
    resources: irq:74 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcffffff
```

Running `uname -r` returns: `5.19.0-35-generic`

I don't know how to see if the driver is available, so I tried to figure out if the module is available using the command below.

Running `modprobe -D rtw_8852ae` returns:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw_8852ae not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-35-generic
```

Running `modprobe -D rtw_core` returns:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw_core not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-35-generic
```

**Edit:**
The HRex39 driver is working at least for now, but since it's deprecated, I wanted to switch to the kernel provided driver. The only annoying thing is that I have to recompile it for every kernel update.

The OS is `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`

**Edit 2:**
I have executed the diagnosis script, but I don't see anything that could point me to the cause of the issue. All I see is the `iwlwifi` being removed, but as far as I know that is only for intel wifi.
Details:
I had unloaded the module with `modprobe -rv 8852be` which returned:

```
rmmod 8852be
rmmod cfg80211
```

Then rebooted... after which it turns out that the driver was loaded again, so I had removed it once more with `modprobe -rv 8852be` then blacklisted it using: `echo "blacklist 8852be" >> /etc/modprobe.d/local-dontload.conf`. I rebooted again and this time I no longed had wifi.

I also tried loading both of the following two modules but to no effect: `modprobe mac80211` and `modprobe cfg80211`

Running the script from: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info returns:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Mar 2023 09:17 EST -0500

Booted last: 10 Mar 2023 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0065 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
platform_profile       16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         819       1  0 09:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_DC_E5_5B_1B_BC_42
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   72f34379-be23-461c-a32e-e81adb42c906 | Pixel 6 Network

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SunnySkies.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SunnySkies | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=SunnySkies
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Mihai Phone.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Mihai Phone | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=Mihai Phone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Nassau (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/local-dontload.conf]
blacklist 8852be

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.763938] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
[    3.765710] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.16 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 3

########## wireless info END ############
```

**Edit 3**: After searching trough the [rtw89](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89) commits it looks to me like it is included in the 6.1 kernel. Specifically [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89?id=915b96c52763e2988e6368b538b487a7138b8fa4) merge I would say it adds the 8852BE driver.

1. Did I understand correctly in which version it is available?
2. Assuming this is true, should I expect the driver to be available when Ubuntu will include the 6.1 kernel?

Comment: The driver version you are showing there that is loaded does not match the GIT repo you have shared.  Git is showing `v1.15.6.0.2-0-gac110bf5.20211029` and yours is showing `v1.15.6.0.2-0-gac110bf5.2021102` which is showing a newer driver has been loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: [/etc/modprobe.d/local-dontload.conf]
blacklist 8852be

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, but my questions are: 
1. Is the driver available in the kernel?
2. If yes, how can I use the driver from the kernel, instead of the 8852be since it's deprecated. I had blacklisted the driver so that I can try to use the kernel driver

Comment: 8852 is not supported yet.

Comment: Do you know where I can monitor to see when it will be available?